# Could not find or load main class Error when changing scala compiler version

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

The default version of Scala complier of Scala IDE for eclipse is **2.12**. It runs well for hello world.
[image]

However when I change the Scala complier version to **2.11** like following:
[image]

Then it shows `Error: Could not find or load main class`

[image]

When I change back to 2.12, it works again.

My question:

My Scala IDE for eclipse version is latest. Why this happens? And what should I do? I have to change to scala 2.11 to load the apache-spark 2.4 jar files. Otherwise it will show errors.

Comment: You can use Spark with 2.12, but if you really want to use 2.11, probably clear cache check the version you have installed of Scala. I would start with those.

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís I need to load jar package of spark into eclipse. Spark 2.4 only allow me to use scala 2.11 in eclipse. I don't know how to tackle this problem. Thank you